# .net 6.0 Integration tests

Tags: integration-testing, .net-6.0

I have a problem that I can`t create HttpClient for integration tests.

I have ready carefully this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing installed
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> in csproj
```

`CustomWebApplicationFactory`:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
        : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HANGFIRE_DASHBOARD_USERNAME", "test");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HANGFIRE_DASHBOARD_PASSWORD", "test");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_URLS", "https://+:1229");

            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
        }
    }
```

`ControllerIntegrationTests`:

```
public class ControllerIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;

        public ControllerIntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            this.factory = factory;
            client = this.factory.CreateClient();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task TestGetEndpointReturnSuccess()
        {
            // Arrange

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/Information");

            // Assert
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

Nothing special in my code, just a simple example. As a result in Output I have :

```
Hosting environment:Development
Now listening on : https://[::]:1229
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

It seems like it started the main application. And I cant move to `Act` in test, because its hanging in CreateClient(). So I can`t finish my test. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forget in your `CustomWebApplicationFactory` to override the `CreateHostBuilder`.

```
protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>();
    });
        
}
```

Try to add this method in your Factory class using the `TStartup`.